# web scraping in R using xpathSApply

Tags: r, web, web-scraping

I've read all previous questions about web scraping in R but couldn't solve my problem. I want to get names of the pictures, (see URL below) and detailed information about  every picture. 
I realize that have to use `xpathSApply` and a loop to take info about every picture. But now i have problem even with taking the name of one from `http://www.wikiart.org/en/search/monet/11`

```
    library(XML)
    url = "http://www.wikiart.org/en/search/monet/1#supersized-search-211804"
    doc = htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes=T)
    pictureName = xpathSApply(doc,"//a[contains(@href, 'title')]",xmlValue)
    pictureName
    ## list()
```

Why does it give me `list()`?

Comment: I know it's yet another thing to learn, but to understand how this works you should probably know how xpath works. It's sorta like regex for parsing XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pictureNames <- xpathSApply(doc,"//a[@class='big rimage']/@title", unname)
```

giving:

```
> head(pictureNames)
[1] "Camille and Jean Monet in the Garden at Argenteuil - Claude Monet"    
[2] "Camille Monet at the Window, Argentuile - Claude Monet"               
[3] "Camille Monet in the Garden - Claude Monet"                           
[4] "Camille Monet in the Garden at the House in Argenteuil - Claude Monet"
[5] "Camille Monet on a Garden Bench - Claude Monet"                       
[6] "Camille Monet On Her Deathbed - Claude Monet"
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! Maybe you know what to read and learne how do what i need: make loop and collect all names with details?

Comment: Please advice, how to specifies what data exactly i want to get. Try to print script to take CompletionDate by analogy with yours. But have result NULL: CompletionDate <- xpathSApply(doc,"//b[@itemprop='dateCreated']/@span") http://www.wikiart.org/en/claude-monet/camille-and-jean-monet-in-the-garden-at-argenteuil

Comment: Try this: `xpathSApply(doc, "//span[@itemprop='dateCreated']", xmlValue) `

Comment: Cool! how do you do it? I got the main principle) but how to get the Material: canvas from here view-source:http://www.wikiart.org/en/claude-monet/a-corner-of-the-garden-at-montgeron-1877

Comment: Try this: `Material <- grep("Material:", xpathSApply(doc, "//p[@class='pt10 b0']", xmlValue), value = TRUE);
strsplit(Material, "[\n\r\t]+")[[1]][3]`